# Backbone.js: populating an event timeline

Tags: backbone.js

In an effort to better understand organization using Backbone, I'm attempting to create a timeline much like Heroku's status page (https://status.heroku.com) and, of course, Facebook.  In short, the timeline simply consists of days containing their respective events.  I may be way off here, but this is the approach I've taken:

The router renders a `days` index view containing sub `day` views.  Contained within each individual `day` are, you guessed it, the `event` views which occur(ed) on that day.  Note: I see no need for the the `day` views to be be backed by a model, only the `event` views, as events are obviously stored in a DB.

Assuming this approach is acceptable (?), here's what's unclear to me: from where do I instantiate (and render) the `event` views?  Should the `day` views fetch their respective `event` views?  If not (and I'm assuming "not"), how do I ensure all `day` views have been rendered before fetching and distributing the events?  Additionally, should there be an `events` index view that fetches and distributes the events?

Any relevant docs or blog posts on this topic would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

Feels like you've already answered your own question - as you said, each individual `day` view contains the `event` views for that day.

So your `day` views would instantiate the `event` views and manage them. You may want to rethink your Model a bit - it may make more sense for the events data to be contain within each day - that would simplify things. In other words, when instantiating a `day`, you pass a `DayModel` to it. Within the `DayModel` is an array of events, and for each you instantiate an `event` view, passing that `EventModel` to it.

This is, of course, all speculative based on the simple description you gave above. Depending on how you want to visually render everything, you may find that the Events need to live outside of the Days.

Just keep in mind that Backbone.js is an extremely "open" framework - there's no one or right way to do something - so do what makes the most sense for your project's specific needs.